# Downsides of increased ASLR entropy

Tags: linux, memory, aslr, memory-management

ASLR allows to randomize the base address of userspace applications. In Linux, the length of the randomized part of the mmap address can be specified via the kernel build config. It is bound by the minimum and maximum values of the respective target architecture.

For example, on arm32 the rand-bits can range from 8 to 16, with the default being set to 8.

`CONFIG_ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS=8`

The above example leads to only 256 possible values with ASLR, loading the process to a random address within a 1 MB range (256 * 4k pages). This is obviously not a number large enough to have a significant impact.

From a security perspective, the more randomness we have for loading the process, the more difficult it becomes for an attacker to guess. Therefore, the maximum possible length for the specific architecture should be used. As this is not the default, there likely is a reason for it.

- Why is the default value of `CONFIG_ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS` not set to `CONFIG_ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS_MAX`?
- What are the downsides of increasing the proportion of the mmap address being randomized?

Comment: Note that the problem with low ASLR bit sizes isn't usually the range where stuff gets mapped (although, NOP sleds being a thing, you do want more than 1MB; are you sure it only masks the least significant byte?) but the fact that it can be brute-forced with a plausible number of attempts. Suppose you have a server with a memory flaw. The attacker doesn't know the ASLR mask, so most attacks will crash rather than achieve code execution. However, if the server starts up again automatically, the attacker can brute-force 256 possibilities quite quickly.